# OOAD and Cassandra. How?

Tags: cassandra, nosql, object-oriented-analysis, ooad

I am trying to wrap my head around doing object oriented analysis and design when your canonical data source is Cassandra.

Specifically:

1. How do I maintain data consistency if data is duplicated among the denormalized cassandra tables?
2. How do I maintain a clean object design? Do I have to have a reference diagram that shows how my domain models map to the denormalized tables?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Essentially, the same way you would if you used a RDBMS as the data-store. Create OO domain-model classes. Access the data-store through an abstract interface, the *persistence layer*, which accepts and provides objects of those classes. Internally, have the persistence layer convert to and from your domain-model classes and Cassandra tables.